# dialog.getWindow() returns a null pointer exception

Tags: android

here is my code:

```
private void handleShow() {
    awakenIfNecessary();
    mDialog = createDialog();
    prepareDialog();

    // If we only have 1 item and it's a simple press action, just do this action.
    if (mAdapter.getCount() == 1
            && mAdapter.getItem(0) instanceof SinglePressAction
            && !(mAdapter.getItem(0) instanceof LongPressAction)) {
        ((SinglePressAction) mAdapter.getItem(0)).onPress();
    } else {
        if (mDialog != null) {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = mDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
            attrs.setTitle("LegacyGlobalActions");
            mDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
            mDialog.show();
            mDialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.STATUS_BAR_DISABLE_EXPAND);
        }
    }
}
```

this from LegacyGlobalActions.java of AOSP,I have made a non-empty judgment，but when run monkey test,crash occured:

> 01-29 23:55:04.201  3378  3574 E AndroidRuntime: *** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: android.ui
>   01-29 23:55:04.201  3378  3574 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window com.android.server.policy.LegacyGlobalActions$GlobalActionsDialog.getWindow()' on a null object reference
>   01-29 23:55:04.201  3378  3574 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.server.policy.LegacyGlobalActions.handleShow(LegacyGlobalActions.java:210)
>   01-29 23:55:04.201  3378  3574 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.server.policy.LegacyGlobalActions.showDialog(LegacyGlobalActions.java:178)
>   01-29 23:55:04.201  3378  3574 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.server.policy.GlobalActions$1.run(GlobalActions.java:108)
>   01-29 23:55:04.201  3378  3574 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
>   01-29 23:55:04.201  3378  3574 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   01-29 23:55:04.201  3378  3574 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>   01-29 23:55:04.201  3378  3574 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
>   01-29 23:55:04.201  3378  3574 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
>   01-29 23:55:04.201  3378  3574 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.server.UiThread.run(UiThread.java:42)
>   5B5C88 01-29 23:55:05.734 20508 20508 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

I'll be very grateful if anyone can tell me why!

Comment: Getwindow can be null if activity which hosted the dialog is not visible,  so make sure while calling getWindow method the activity is visible not in background or stop state.

Comment: thanks,but according to the log,i think dialog is null instead of dialog.getwindow() is null,

Comment: is it dialog fragment or a regular dialog? this code that you posted is within the custom dialog or you are using the dialog from outside?

Answer (score 0):

you try

```
private void handleShow() {
    awakenIfNecessary();
    mDialog = createDialog();
    prepareDialog();

    // If we only have 1 item and it's a simple press action, just do this action.
    if (mAdapter.getCount() == 1
            && mAdapter.getItem(0) instanceof SinglePressAction
            && !(mAdapter.getItem(0) instanceof LongPressAction)) {
        ((SinglePressAction) mAdapter.getItem(0)).onPress();
    } else {
        if (mDialog != null) {   
            mDialog.show();
WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = mDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
            attrs.setTitle("LegacyGlobalActions");
            mDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
            mDialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.STATUS_BAR_DISABLE_EXPAND);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thinks ,but could you tell me why can do this?

Comment: Because dialog is not show. You must show dialog first then you use mDialog.getWindow() will return not null.

Answer (score 0):

Although it has been a long time, I still want to answer. First of all, the window is initialized in the constructor and is definitely not null under normal circumstances. And according to the crash “GlobalActionsDialog.getWindow ()’ on a null object reference”, it can be 100% certain that your Dialog is null rather than other reasons. According to your code, you have already judged “mDialog != null” in advance, so there are only three possibilities: 1. You changed the code but did not run it; 2. Although it was run, Android Studio often has problems and can be uninstalled and tried again; 3. In rare cases, you changed the value of mDialog in a sub-thread.